# How to get the value of Integer.MAX_VALUE in Java without using the Integer class

Tags: java, integer, int, max

I have this question that has completely stumped me.
I have to create a variable that equals Integer.MAX_VALUE... (in Java)

```
// The answer must contain balanced parentesis
public class Exercise{

  public static void main(String [] arg){
    [???]
    assert (Integer.MAX_VALUE==i);
  }
}
```

The challenge is that the source code cannot contain the words "Integer", "Float", "Double" or any digits (0 - 9).

Comment: What? I don't understand... `int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`? Or just look at the source: `@Native public static final int MAX_VALUE = 0x7fffffff;`

Comment: Just do `int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: @JoshM @Christian `The issue is that the answer cannot contain: "Integer", "Float", "Double", and digits (0 - 9)`

Comment: I guess it can contain `int` (instead of `Integer`) then.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a succinct method:

```
int ONE = "x".length();
int i = -ONE >>> ONE; //unsigned shift
```

This works because the max integer value in binary is all ones, except the top (sign) bit, which is zero. But -1 in twos compliment binary is all ones, so by bit shifting -1 one bit to the right, you get the max value.

```
11111111111111111111111111111111 // -1 in twos compliment
01111111111111111111111111111111 // max int (2147483647)
```

Answer (score 7):

As others have said.

```
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

is what you want.

Integer.MAX_VALUE, is a "static constant" inside of the "wrapper class" Integer that is simply the max value. Many classes have static constants in them that are helpful.

Comment: Bzzzt ... your answer contains `Integer`!  But thanks for playing :-)

Comment: Whoops! I completely missed that (only and most important) constraint

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
int ONE = "X".length();
int max = ONE;
while (max < max + ONE) {
   max = max + ONE;
}
```

or lots of variants.

(The trick you were missing is how to "create" an integer value without using a numeric literal or a number wrapper class.  Once you have created `ONE`, the rest is simple ...)

Comment: Sorry, but I have to do this for bragging rights... see [my version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22889389/256196) :)

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but here goes:

```
int two = "xx".length();
int thirtyone = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx".length();
System.out.println(Math.pow(two, thirtyone)-1);
```

How did I go? :p

I do like that bitshift one though...

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the answer cannot contain: "Integer", "Float", "Double", and digits (0 - 9)

There are other things in Java which can be represented as an `Integer`, for example a `char`:

```
char aCharacter = 'a';
int asInt = (int) aCharacter;
System.out.println(asInt); //Output: 97
```

You can also add chars together in this manner:

```
char aCharacter = 'a';
char anotherCharacter = 'b';
int sumOfCharacters = aCharacter + anotherCharacter;
System.out.println(sumOfCharacters); //Output: 195
```

With this information, you should be able to work out how to get to `2147483647`on your own.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so an Integer can only take certain values. This is from MIN_VALUE to MAX_VALUE where the minimum value is negative.

If you increase an integer past this upper bound the value will wrap around and become the lowest value possible. e.g. MAX_VALUE+1 = MIN_VALUE.

Equally, if you decrease an integer past the lower bound it will wrap around and become the largest possible value. e.g. MIN_VALUE-1 = MAX_VALUE.

Therefore a simple program that instantiates an int, decrements it until it wraps around and returns that value should give you the same value as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

```
public static void main(String [] arg) {

    int i = -1

    while (i<0) {
        i--;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works....

```
int i = Short.MIN_VALUE 
       *Short.MIN_VALUE 
       *(Short.MAX_VALUE/Short.MAX_VALUE + Short.MAX_VALUE/Short.MAX_VALUE) 
       -(Short.MAX_VALUE/Short.MAX_VALUE);
i = Math.abs(i);
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76261993/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)