# Find the maximum value of a float without using Float.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, floating-point

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22888961/how-to-get-the-value-of-integer-max-value-in-java-without-using-the-integer-clas/22889005#22889005) one. As far as I can tell, you cannot bit shift a float in Java. If that is the case how would I got about calculating the maximum value of a float without using `Float.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE This tells you the exact value of Float.MAX_VALUE, you can just use some kind of math to calculate this value.

Comment: `Math.nextDown(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` or `Math.nextDown(1f/0f)` (shouldn't be to hard to create that numbers if needed {digits not allowed})

Answer (score 1):

(2-2^-23)·2^127 is the maximum value for a float

```
float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(0x7f7fffff);
System.out.println(f);
float f1 =  0x1.fffffeP+127f;
System.out.println(f1);
```

both print 3.4028235E38 as in the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE)

Or you can play around using math to get the same value

Comment: wouldn't that be the same as using `3.4028235e+38f`directly?

Comment: not sure if it is allowed, at least not by the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22888961/85421) this question is based on, but that is up to OP

Answer (score 1):

Brute force. This method does not depend on knowing the structure of a float, just that 1 is in the finite float range, and that `Math.nextUp(float)` and `Float.isFinite(float)` both work. It could be made faster by first doubling until next is infinite, then using nextUp.

```
public strictfp class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float max = maxFloat(1);
        System.out.println(max);
    }


    /**
     * @param f A starting point.
     * @return Largest finite float.
     */
    static float maxFloat(float f) {
        float next = Math.nextUp(f);
        while(Float.isFinite(next)) {
            f = next;
            next = Math.nextUp(f);
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Output:

3.4028235E38